# How to set the Button Image tint color?

Tags: ios, xcode

Button image icon tint color changing on click in iOS.
Here is the image of what is happening.

[image]

Problem: the color is the *default* one, not the custom color I have set.
Question: how to set a *custom* tint color for that button?

Comment: show your tried code? whats not working?

Comment: I have given image to button in storyboard. My button type is custom

Comment: So where is the question?

Comment: Setting the tint color makes the image single-colored, this is expected behavior.

Comment: but my tint color is default

Comment: just past your code? and refer this link as well [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
if let btnImg = yourBtnOutlet.imageView?.image {
       yourBtnOutlet.setImage(btnImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
       yourBtnOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.red
 }
```